# How to get a specific entity attribute using the id stored on another one?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So i have a postulations entity which contains the id of another one called annoncesemplois, what i'm trying to do is using the idAnnEmp stored in entity postulations and get the title(titre) of annoncesemplois from the database, and displayed using twig

Will doctrine ManytoMany or other associations help ?

```
/**
 * Annonceemplois
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="annonceemplois", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_ANNONCEEMPLOIS_idUser", columns={"idUser"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Annonceemplois
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IDANNEMP", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idannemp;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DATECREATION", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datecreation;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PRIX", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $prix;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="TITRE", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DESCRIPTION", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DUREE", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $duree;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idUser", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * 
     */
    private $iduser;
```

```
/**
 * Postulation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="postulation", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_POSTULATION_id", columns={"id"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_POSTULATION_idAnnEmp", columns={"idAnnEmp"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Postulation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IDPOSTULATION", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idpostulation;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="DATEPOSTULATION", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datepostulation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ETAT", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $etat;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idAnnEmp", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $idannemp;
```

This is where im trying to show it

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body posts">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {% for post in postulations %}
                                    <div class="post-item">
                                        <div class="post-title">
                                           {{ post.idannemp.titre }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="post-date"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> {{ post.datepostulation | date }} / {{ post.etat }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relations to get the Related Entities. For example:

> In Postulations.php add oneToMany relation and initialize the field:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->annonceemplois = new ArrayCollection();    
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Annonceemplois", 
 mappedBy="postulation")
 */
    private $annonceemplois;
```

> In Annonceemplois.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Postulation", 
 inversedBy="annoceemplois")
 */
    private $postulation;
```

Comment: I did that but when i enter post.annonceemplois.Titre give an error titre, getTitre don't exist

Comment: Neither the property "Titre" nor one of the methods "Titre()", "getTitre()"/"isTitre()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".  

Still this error, im new to this i pretty much have no clear idea what to do.

Comment: Did you insert data and the mapping with database is correct?

Comment: `
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $postulations = $em->getRepository('SmartStartsBundle:Postulation')->findAll();
        $annonceemplois = $em->getRepository('SmartStartsBundle:Annonceemplois')->findAll();
        foreach ($postulations as $post){
           foreach ($annonceemplois as $an){
               if ($post->getIdannemp()===$an->getIdannemp()){
                   $post->setAnnonce($an);
               }
           }
        }
        return $this->render('postulation/index.html.twig', array(
            'postulations' =>$postulations,
        ));
`

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution :

```
class Annonce 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Postulation", mappedBy="annonce")
     *
     */
    private $postulations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postulations = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class Postulation
{
   /**
    *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Annonce", inversedBy="postulations")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="annonce_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $annonce;
}
```

in twig you can use this :

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body posts">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {% for post in postulations %}
                                    <div class="post-item">
                                        <div class="post-title">
                                           {{ post.annonce.titre }}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="post-date"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> {{ post.datepostulation | date }} / {{ post.etat }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It seems like it gets to it for now, but its saying its a null variable, what am i missing here ?

Comment: Impossible to access an attribute ("titre") on a null variable.

Comment: logically one should not have a postulation without ad. we can add `nullable = false` for `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="annonce_id", referencedColumnName="id")`